# QMessage in a function thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, popup, qmessagebox

I want to do a popup when the function in a thread finish but when it run the popup the program crash. I tried doing a thread in the main function thread but crash the app.

I put a large and slow funtion in a thread to not crash the GUI but I want when this slow function finish, run a popup with QMessageBox, my sollution work but when I press the 'Ok' button in the popup crash the program, but I dont want that, so I tried to make a thread from the main thread but do the same, only crash the program.

I want something like this:

```
def popup():
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setWindowTitle("Alert")
    ...
    a = msg.exec_()

def slow_func():
    time.sleep(10) # exemple of slow
    popup() # when I press 'Ok' crash so I tried...

# I tried...

def slow_func():
    time.sleep(10) # exemple of slow
    threading.Thread(target=popup).start() # still crashing

threading.Thread(target=slow_func).start()
```

I don't know how to do it, I tried a thread in a thread but still crashing when I press 'Ok' button. The popup works but crash the app when I press 'Ok'

I'm in Windows 11 using python 3.10 and PyQt 5.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You must not use any GUI functions outside of the main thread.** So you can not call `popup()` from your calculation thread and you can't create a new thread in your calculation thread and have that call it. You must make the main thread call it.

For possible solutions see [How to properly execute GUI operations in Qt main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34135624/10171966)

In short: Use the [signal-slot-mechanism](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) or [QMetaObject::invokeMethod()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

Comment: ok thanks! I'm going to apply connect()